# Way to implement "Get all strings with Levenshtein distance less than X"

Tags: data-structures, levenshtein-distance

I'm wondering whether there's an efficient data structure to perform "Retrieve all strings with levenshtein distance less than X".

Few things I'm interested in:

- Explanation of the algorithm.
- Is there an existing implementation in existing database / programming langauge?
- Paper / article that I can refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is *nearest neighborer search in a metric space* with levenshtein distance as the metric (or distance) function

a [VP-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP-tree) is one of the ways of solving that problem

this [Python VP-tree implementation](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/blog/01164790008) is a working demo that shows how a VP-tree works run it on say a word list it provides an interactive shell where you type a word and it returns the words in that list that are no more then X distance from the word you typed

Comment: Cool. I don't know why it never occurred to me that people would try to solve this problem in general metric spaces. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) with each generation being just one 'edit' away from the previous - and with checks in place to ensure that a string appears in one-and-only-one level.

This would be easily implemented using a couple of hashsets / hashtables in a pair of loops.